# No SSl/TLS CA certificates using nimble

Tags: nimble

I am using Msys2 to run and compile c/nim programs, I cloned a repo that has a `.nim` file that I want to run but didn't have ceration packages such as `nimcrypto` so I used the command

```
nimble install nimcrypto
```

but got this  error

```
$ nimble install nimcrypto
    Prompt: No local packages.json found, download it from internet? [y/N]
    Answer: y
Downloading Official package list
       Tip: 5 messages have been suppressed, use --verbose to show them.
     Error: Refresh failed
        ... Could not download: No SSL/TLS CA certificates found.
```

Where do I get these certificates from and how do I add them to nimble

downloaded nimble using [this](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-nimble?repo=mingw64)

downloaded nim using [this](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-nim)

```
Nim Compiler Version 1.4.6 [Windows: amd64]
Compiled at 2021-05-03
Copyright (c) 2006-2020 by Andreas Rumpf

git hash: 09db720eff0ec9e160debab126af37b1a4df296c
active boot switches: -d:release
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually downloaded the cert to `/usr/bin` from [this link](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/782#issuecomment-785531690)

and this seems to solve the issue